# Free Graphical User Interface to prepare inputs for LAMMPS

Tags: molecular-dynamics, software-recommendations, lammps, graphical-user-interface

Searching the LAMMPS site, I found some software capable to prepare LAMMPS inputs but they are not free and other software to analyze the output.

I would like to know other package (with Graphical User Interface) capable to prepare the input files in order to run a molecular dynamics simulation using LAMMPS.

Comment: I guess it depends a bit on what you want, but Avogadro2 has a LAMMPS interface. I don't know if it does everything you might want (because LAMMPS has many options).

Answer (score 7):

I’m currently working on something like this. It is called Atomify, and runs lammps, visualization and analysis in Python purely in the web browser. You can take a look at https://andeplane.github.io/atomify/

Would love some feedback and suggestions on what you need.

Edit: Oython is a rarely used language, so switched to Python!

Comment: Oython? Are you sure the O is supposed to be capitalized?

Comment: Haha, I learned that not too many people enjoy Oython, so switched to Python now ;p